# What is the Southern Baptist belief regarding speaking in tongues?

Tags: southern-baptist, speaking-in-tongues

I have yet to see anyone speaking in tongues in a Southern Baptist church.  Having said that, the lack of speaking in tongues does not necessarily mean that Southern Baptists *never* speak in tongues or that they do not believe in it as a general rule.  Clearly they seem to avoid it.

Nonetheless, what is the Southern Baptist belief regarding speaking in tongues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Southern Baptist denomination doesn't hold any particular stance regarding the gift of speaking in tongues.

If you took a survey of all the different Southern Baptist churches, you would come up with a variety of beliefs on the subject.

From their FAQ regarding [speaking in tongues](http://www.sbc.net/aboutus/faqs.asp#8):

> Probably most believe that the "gift of tongues" as described in the Bible ceased upon the completion of the Bible. Some may view speaking in tongues as a spiritual gift given to some Christians enabling them to communicate the Gospel to foreign cultures in a language the speaker had not known previously.  A very small minority might accept what is commonly practiced today in charismatic churches as valid.

There has been some [debate among Southern Baptists regarding speaking in tongues](http://www.christianpost.com/news/southern-baptists-debate-over-speaking-in-tongues-27177/), with varying views mentioned above.

Comment: This seems odd to me. Do they have a general doctrinal statement on gifts or any relevant comments about cecasionism?

Comment: @Caleb Actually that FAQ question is about *"speaking in tongues" and other "charismatic" gifts*.  I think in general they just avoid thinking about the question as a denomination.  I suspect that there are a few topics that are like this (acceptability of alcohol, for example).

Answer (score 2):

I am a Baptist.
In many Baptist churches it is thought that the power to speak in tongues, or prophesy, etc. is evil, and must come from the devil.  However, although a rule, it has it's exceptions.  For example, my church takes the exact opposite stance, saying that it would be quenching the spirit to suppress that gift.

In Christ!

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This answer needs more support. It needs sources and citations, if necessary, to support what you are saying. Otherwise, it just looks like your opinion. Please add more to it to make a truly academic answer. Thank you. References: [Guidelines for writing effective answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1920) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/886)

Comment: Not all baptists are Southern Baptists. Are you a member of a SBC church?

Comment: @curiousdannii No.  Should I delete my answer?  Or does it still apply?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience- Southern Baptist don’t want speaking in tongues to be a distraction from speaking in your native tongue. They do not deny it exist but are turned off by many people pretending to speak in tongues, just repeating the same 5 words over and over. Nor do they want meetings disrupted with what no one else understands. If a person with the gift of tongues goes on a mission trip, they are asked to agree not to speak in tongues while on the trip.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Since you do not approve of my answer then you may delete it.  I answered based on my experience with Southern Baptist. No other answer could claim this.

Comment: I never said I disapproved. I am welcoming you to the site and giving you some advice so you can have a better experience.